# React: How to sort items according to date?

Tags: reactjs, sorting

I am creating events, by picking dates from React date-picker component in a form. I am displaying them in a table like so:

tableA.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
      class TableRow extends Component {
       render() {
        return (
         <tr>
           <td>
             {this.props.obj.event_name} 
              <br></br>
              {moment(this.props.obj.startDate).format("MMMM D, Y") 
              //startDate is of type Date 
     </td>
    </tr>
);}}
```

This is where I am retrieving the array from the database.

// index.js

```
   componentDidMount(){
   axios.get('http://localhost:4000/event')
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({ event: response.data });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
}
 tabRow(){
  return this.state.event.map(function(object, i){
      return <TableRow obj={object} key={i} />;
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <table className="table table-striped" style={{ marginTop: 20 , width:700}}>
        <tbody>
          { this.tabRow() }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

}
Right now it is displaying events in a list in the order of creation, the one created first displayed first in table. How can I sort them with respect to date, in ascending order, so that the event with the oldest date will display first?

Comment: Please add sample data of your table and full code from which we can understand your flow.

Comment: This worked for me:tabRow(){
  var events = this.state.event
 events.sort((a,b) => {
  return new Date(a.startDate).getTime() -
   new Date(b.startDate).getTime()
 } ) ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the reverse() will change the original array,so better to copy it and then to reverse it.

If the array is sorted with create times ,the reverse will make the earliest created be the last one of the array.

```
let User = ...
let new_User = User.reverse();
{new_User.map((item) => {
  //display
})}
```

---

Second, use the sort function in array.It can add a function to define the sorting method.Since the code has used moment().The moment library has isBefore function to compare the time.

```
function compare(){// define the compare method
   if(moment(t2).isBefore(t1)){
       return 1
   }else if (moment(t1).isBefore(t2)){
       return -1
   }else {
       return 0
   }
}
array.sort(compare)
```

---

#### Edit:

```
function reverse_event(object1,object2){
   let t1 = moment(object1.event_name)
   let t2 = moment(object2.event_name)
   if(t2.isBefore(t1)){
       return -1
   }else if (t1.isBefore(t2)){
       return 1
   }else {
       return 0
   }
}
tabRow(){
  let events = this.state.event
  let events_reverse = events.sort(reverse_event)
  return events_reverse.map(function(object, i){
      return <TableRow obj={object} key={i} />;
  });
}
```

Comment: This is where I am retrieving them from the database: componentDidMount(){
      axios.get('http://localhost:4000/event')
        .then(response => {
          this.setState({ event: response.data });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        })
    }

Comment: I have changed my answer.However,by the way,this kind of question always should be processed by the backend.

Comment: I implemented something by taking cues from your code. Was trying to see whether it sorts them at all. It seems to not do anything and the events are listed without any sorting. tabRow(){
  let events = this.state.event
 events.sort((a,b) => a.event_name > b.event_name) ;
 
  return events.map(function(object, i){
      return <TableRow obj={object} key={i} />;
  });
}

Comment: Well,are you trying to sort the string array?@user5938020

Comment: If you want to sort the array with the alphabetical order，just use this events.sort().reverse().@user5938020

Comment: This worked for me:tabRow(){ var events = this.state.event events.sort((a,b) => { return new Date(a.startDate).getTime() - new Date(b.startDate).getTime() } ) ;

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the dates to the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00, using getTime(), and sort the events based on these values, you get what yiu want.

Comment: I do have the dates that are being saved in this format when the user picks them from the datepicker. The timestamp is there. However, how can I sort it based on these time stamps?

Comment: When you save the date, also convert with getTime and save the result as well. Then use these saved values to sort.

Answer (score 0):

Cool Just try this....

```js
dateArray.sort((a, b) => this.desc(a, b));


desc = (a, b) => {
  const aDate = a.date1 ? new Date(a.date1) : new Date(a.date2);
  const bDate = b.date1 ? new Date(b.date1) : new Date(b.date2);
  return bDate.getTime() - aDate.getTime();
 };
```